# Default wrappers not loading with SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend, haml, simple-form

I have two files in `config/initializers` relating to the SimpleForm gem - one is a pretty standard configuration (I think it's the default), and the other defines some wrappers. The standard configuration has had the `wrapper_mappings` options modified to equal `{boolean: :inline_checkbox}` with the hopes of loading my `inline_checkbox` wrapper from the other file.

- Views can use the wrapper (I tried it on a boolean `f.input` element), but won't take it as the default when defined up there. I've tried swapping out `boolean` for `check_box` to no avail.
- I've tried placing the definition `config.wrapper_mappings = {boolean: :inline_checkbox}` in both files, which also hasn't worked.

Worst case, I'll just apply the wrapper to *each and every element*...but I'd sooner not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Check that `config.wrapper_mappings` isn't overridden anywhere else and reload the server.